# Median values in probability distribution where two median values can possibly occur?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, median

I have a relatively basic question, I will keep it short, sharp and shiny.

In a probability distribution lets suppose $P_1 =0.5, P_2 = 0.0, P_3 =0.5$

All three outcomes share a slice of the median constant of $0.5$. Which outcome is the median awarded to? I assume the convention is to award it to the first outcome that encounters the $0.5$ value - $P_1$, but I could be wrong, and this is bugging me...

I apologise for the elementary question in retrospect but would love an answer.

Comment: What is your definition of the median?

Comment: If those are the probabilities of the values $1,2,3$ then any value in the interval $[1,3]$ might be seen as the median

Comment: @Raskolnikov well I suppose in a probability distribution that adds up to 1, the median is the value that covers the middle-most value of 0.5.

Comment: @Henry Oh yes perhaps $P_e=\lim_{x \to 0} 0.5+x$